# Services communication in consul

Tags: microservices, consul, service-discovery

I am developing several services, and use consul as the service registry. I'm able to register all of my services to the consul.

And now for the next thing to do, I need to be able to communicate from service A to service B.

Without a service registry, usually what I did was simply dispatch a client HTTP request from service A to service B.

But since now I already have service discovery in place, should I get the service B host address via consul and then dispatch a client HTTP request to the service B host address something like that? Or does the consul also provide an API gateway, so I only need to dispatch my client HTTP request from service A to the consul, and then the consul will automatically forward it to the destination?

Also if there is relevant documentation about my case, I would be very glad to take a look at it? (I can't find the relevant documentation, probably my google search keyword is wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consul supports two methods for service discovery, DNS and HTTP.

Applications can perform DNS lookups against their local Consul agent which exposes a DNS server on port 8600 (you can also configure [DNS forwarding](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/dns-forwarding)). For example, an application can issue an `A` record query for `web.service.consul` and Consul will return a list of healthy instance endpoints for the `web` service. `SRV` lookups are also supported in order to retrieve the IP and port for a given service. The DNS interface also supports querying endpoints by service tag and data center. Details can be found at [Consul.io: DNS - Service Lookups](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/dns#service-lookups).

HTTP-based service discovery can be performed by querying the [`/v1/health/service/:name`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/health#list-nodes-for-service) endpoint against the local agent. The following will return a full list of healthy and unhealthy endpoints for the service `nginx`.

```sh
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/health/service/nginx
```

You can use the `passing` query parameter to restrict the output to only healthy services.

```sh
$ curl "http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/health/service/nginx?passing"
```

I recommend reviewing the guide [Register a Service with Consul Service Discovery](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/get-started-service-discovery?in=consul/getting-started) for more info on registering and querying services from the catalog.

Lastly, API gateways like Traefik and Solo's Gloo support using Consul for service discovery (see Traefik's [Consul Catalog Provider](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/consul-catalog/) and Gloo's [Consul Services](https://docs.solo.io/gloo/latest/guides/traffic_management/destination_types/consul_services/)). You could configure your services to route requests to these gateways, and allow the gateway to forward to the backend destination.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting the list of services info from the consul, and then perform name matching on it then get the service address.

I use this endpoint to get the list of the services and it's data:

```
http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/services
```

So it's the client-side discovery I guess.